# Breakaway Point in Root-Locus

Tags: roots, control-theory

Can anyone explain me why the breakaway points in Root-Locus are only on the real axis?

Answer (score 0):

Root locus is the graphical representation of the evolution of the characteristic equation. i.e. it shows how the roots vary as you vary the value of $k$.

Coming to roots of the characteristic equation, which is a polynomial, we know that they are either real or occur in complex conjugates. i.e of the form $x \pm iy$. And further, the roots depend continuously on the value of $k$.

Hence, as we vary $k$, the only possibility for break away is when we travel on the real axis (roots are real) and then break away (roots become complex in conjugate pairs).

Comment: Im not sure I understand why it has to be real..

Comment: Lets take a simple example. Consider the char. equation $x^2+kx+1$.

Comment: what if we have 2 pairs of complex roots. why each 2 of them won't meet somewhere in imaginary point?